# How to create a scale effect in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-transitions, scale

I've got the following `CSS` transition: http://jsfiddle.net/cW3Ts/

This keeps jumping and is not compatible/buggy  in some browsers so I would like to create it using `jQuery`. I've got the `fadeIn` sorted as such (example):

```
$(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#58a5e1'}, 400);
```

Unfortunately, I am finding it difficult to scale/ease the div in and out on hover. I have tried animate height and width but this does create the same effect. I have also looked at `jQuery` UI scale and I can not get the scale to work on a dic when hovered, their example shows a toggle and it just breaks the hover function altogether. Does anyone know a solution or a plugin I could use so I can get the similar effect that the `CSS` does (scale and ease).

I would be so grateful as I've been researching all day and almost ready to give up!

Comment: jQuery will do no better than CSS3 (eventually browser support, nothing more)

Comment: Nothing the jQuery UI Scale will solve or is it just as bad? Oh dear! Just i have another div on top and with the jumping pixel it makes my button look horrible!

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"?

Comment: @EddieJamsession it means that some browsers don't support CSS3, you know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but I think the css transitions look a lot smoother for browsers that support them. You may want to consider using a conditional comment or something like that so the script is only used when necessary.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/cW3Ts/11/)

```
$('.cta').hover(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('dark-grey-bg', 800).addClass('blue-bg-fade', 400).animate({
        height: $(this).height() * 1.05,
        width: $(this).width() * 1.05
    }, 300);
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('grey').addClass('white').animate({
        fontSize: '105%'
    }, 300);

}, function () {
    $(this).addClass('dark-grey-bg', 400).removeClass('blue-bg-fade', 800).animate({
        height: $(this).height() / 1.05,
        width: $(this).width() / 1.05
    }, 300);

    $(this).find('a').removeClass('white', 400).addClass('grey', 800).animate({
        fontSize: '100%'
    }, 300);
});
```

Here's an example of a conditional comment that should work for IE9 and below

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    // insert script here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, so the lines added are that it gets the current height and width and scales it 1.05 (at the speed 300). and then returns the width and height- great! I can use this on some buttons but on my play buttons i have a div over the top of the button and the play image goes inside the button when it animates- i will figure another solution for this as well as IE!